# match string length; find and Replace; remove HTML tags in C++

Tags: c++, html, string, visual-studio-2010

here is my question 
I'm trying to remove HTML tags, simply format them (like new line for every information), and write other program to extract useful information later.
I have read the data into a large string array so far.
here is my thought: find all tags which is in <> and replace them with blank. after checking online, I saw some programs that can do the find and replacement part. 
Because different HTML tags have different length, so I'm wondering is there a way in C++ that can detect any length of the tag, as long as it's in the <>. and then just replace them.
here is one sample code of HTML

```
<div style="width: 200px;"><strong>Balance Sheets (USD $)<br></strong></div>
```

and I hope to get after operations:

```
Balance Sheets (USD $)
```

could anyone help? or does anyone have a better idea to deal with this task? Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<DOCUMENT>
<TYPE>XML
<SEQUENCE>33
<FILENAME>R2.htm
<DESCRIPTION>IDEA: XBRL DOCUMENT
<TEXT>
<html>
  <head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
    <link rel="StyleSheet" type="text/css" href="report.css"><script type="text/javascript" src="Show.js">/* Do Not Remove This Comment */</script></head>
  <body><span style="display: none;">v2.4.0.6</span><table class="report" border="0" cellspacing="2" id="ID0EQAAG">
      <tr>
        <th class="tl" colspan="1" rowspan="1">
          <div style="width: 200px;"><strong>Balance Sheets (USD $)<br></strong></div>
        </th>
        <th class="th">
          <div>Dec. 31, 2012</div>
        </th>
        <th class="th">
          <div>Dec. 31, 2011</div>
        </th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="re">
        <td class="pl" style="border-bottom: 0px;" valign="top"><a class="a" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="top.Show.showAR( this, 'defref_tpoi_CurrentAssetsAbstract', window );"><strong>Current assets:</strong></a></td>
        <td class="text">&#xA0;<span></span></td>
        <td class="text">&#xA0;<span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ro">
        <td class="pl" style="border-bottom: 0px;" valign="top"><a class="a" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="top.Show.showAR( this, 'defref_us-gaap_CashAndCashEquivalentsAtCarryingValue', window );">Cash and cash equivalents</a></td>
        <td class="nump">$ 106,999<span></span></td>
        <td class="nump">$ 52,109<span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="re">
        <td class="pl" style="border-bottom: 0px;" valign="top"><a class="a" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="top.Show.showAR( this, 'defref_us-gaap_AccountsReceivableNetCurrent', window );">Accounts receivable</a></td>
        <td class="nump">110,720<span></span></td>
        <td class="nump">61,218<span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ro">
        <td class="pl" style="border-bottom: 0px;" valign="top"><a class="a" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="top.Show.showAR( this, 'defref_tpoi_AccountsReceivableRelatedParty', window );">Accounts receivable - related party</a></td>
        <td class="nump">1,527<span></span></td>
        <td class="text">&#xA0;<span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="reu">
        <td class="pl" style="border-bottom: 0px;" valign="top"><a class="a" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="top.Show.showAR( this, 'defref_us-gaap_AssetsCurrent', window );">Total current assets</a></td>
        <td class="nump">219,246<span></span></td>
        <td class="nump">113,327<span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ro">
        <td class="pl" style="border-bottom: 0px;" valign="top"><a class="a" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="top.Show.showAR( this, 'defref_us-gaap_PropertyPlantAndEquipmentNet', window );">Property and equipment, net</a></td>
        <td class="nump">152,724<span></span></td>
        <td class="nump">160,454<span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="re">
        <td class="pl" style="border-bottom: 0px;" valign="top"><a class="a" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="top.Show.showAR( this, 'defref_us-gaap_CapitalizedSoftwareDevelopmentCostsForSoftwareSoldToCustomers', window );">Capitalized software development costs</a></td>
        <td class="nump">188,371<span></span></td>
        <td class="text">&#xA0;<span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ro">
        <td class="pl" style="border-bottom: 0px;" valign="top"><a class="a" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="top.Show.showAR( this, 'defref_us-gaap_IntangibleAssetsNetExcludingGoodwill', window );">Intangible assets, net</a></td>
        <td class="nump">59,151<span></span></td>
        <td class="nump">59,151<span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="re">
        <td class="pl" style="border-bottom: 0px;" valign="top"><a class="a" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="top.Show.showAR( this, 'defref_us-gaap_OtherAssetsCurrent', window );">Other assets</a></td>
        <td class="nump">11,622<span></span></td>
        <td class="nump">15,470<span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="rou">
        <td class="pl" style="border-bottom: 0px;" valign="top"><a class="a" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="top.Show.showAR( this, 'defref_us-gaap_NoncurrentAssets', window );">Total long term assets</a></td>
        <td class="nump">411,868<span></span></td>
        <td class="nump">235,075<span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="reu">
        <td class="pl" style="border-bottom: 0px;" valign="top"><a class="a" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="top.Show.showAR( this, 'defref_us-gaap_Assets', window );">Total assets</a></td>
        <td class="nump">631,114<span></span></td>
        <td class="nump">348,402<span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ro">
        <td class="pl" style="border-bottom: 0px;" valign="top"><a class="a" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="top.Show.showAR( this, 'defref_tpoi_CurrentLiabilitiesAbstract', window );"><strong>Current liabilities:</strong></a></td>
        <td class="text">&#xA0;<span></span></td>
        <td class="text">&#xA0;<span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="re">
        <td class="pl" style="border-bottom: 0px;" valign="top"><a class="a" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="top.Show.showAR( this, 'defref_us-gaap_AccountsPayableCurrent', window );">Accounts payable</a></td>
        <td class="nump">50,866<span></span></td>
        <td class="nump">70,253<span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ro">
        <td class="pl" style="border-bottom: 0px;" valign="top"><a class="a" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="top.Show.showAR( this, 'defref_us-gaap_AccruedLiabilitiesCurrent', window );">Accrued liabilities</a></td>
        <td class="nump">1,452<span></span></td>
        <td class="nump">6,752<span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="reu">
        <td class="pl" style="border-bottom: 0px;" valign="top"><a class="a" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="top.Show.showAR( this, 'defref_us-gaap_Liabilities', window );">Total current liabilities</a></td>
        <td class="nump">52,318<span></span></td>
        <td class="nump">77,005<span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ro">
        <td class="pl" style="border-bottom: 0px;" valign="top"><a class="a" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="top.Show.showAR( this, 'defref_us-gaap_OtherAccruedLiabilitiesNoncurrent', window );">Other non current liabilities, accrued interest</a></td>
        <td class="nump">7,500<span></span></td>
        <td class="nump">1,500<span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="re">
        <td class="pl" style="border-bottom: 0px;" valign="top"><a class="a" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="top.Show.showAR( this, 'defref_us-gaap_NotesPayableCurrent', window );">Notes payable</a></td>
        <td class="nump">50,000<span></span></td>
        <td class="nump">50,000<span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ro">
        <td class="pl" style="border-bottom: 0px;" valign="top"><a class="a" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="top.Show.showAR( this, 'defref_us-gaap_DueToRelatedPartiesCurrent', window );">Notes payable - related party</a></td>
        <td class="nump">100,000<span></span></td>
        <td class="nump">100,000<span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="reu">
        <td class="pl" style="border-bottom: 0px;" valign="top"><a class="a" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="top.Show.showAR( this, 'defref_us-gaap_OtherLiabilitiesCurrent', window );">Total long-term liabilities</a></td>
        <td class="nump">157,500<span></span></td>
        <td class="nump">151,500<span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="rou">
        <td class="pl" style="border-bottom: 0px;" valign="top"><a class="a" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="top.Show.showAR( this, 'defref_us-gaap_LiabilitiesCurrent', window );">Total liabilities</a></td>
        <td class="nump">209,818<span></span></td>
        <td class="nump">228,505<span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="re">
        <td class="pl" style="border-bottom: 0px;" valign="top"><a class="a" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="top.Show.showAR( this, 'defref_tpoi_ShareholdersEquityAbstract', window );"><strong>Shareholders&#x2019; equity:</strong></a></td>
        <td class="text">&#xA0;<span></span></td>
        <td class="text">&#xA0;<span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="ro">
        <td class="pl" style="border-bottom: 0px;" valign="top"><a class="a" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="top.Show.showAR( this, 'defref_us-gaap_CommonStockValue', window );">Common stock, $0 par value, 30,000,000 shares authorized, 13,312,302 and 9,312,302 shares issued and outstanding at December 31, 2012 and 2011, respectively</a></td>
        <td class="nump">1,542,651<span></span></td>
        <td class="nump">946,151<span></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="re">
        <td class="pl" style="border-bottom: 0px;" valign="top"><a class="a" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="top.Show.showAR( this, 'defref_us-gaap_AccumulatedDepreciationDepletionAndAmortizationPropertyPlantAndEquipment', window );">Accumulated deficit</a></td>
        <td class="num">(1,145,758)<span></span></td>
        <td class="num">(837,310)<span></span></td>
      </tr>

**Many many HTML code here...... Many Many Many**
                    <td><strong> Name:</strong></td>
                    <td><nobr>us-gaap_StockholdersEquity</nobr></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="padding-right: 4px;"><nobr><strong> Namespace Prefix:</strong></nobr></td>
                    <td>us-gaap_</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><strong> Data Type:</strong></td>
                    <td>xbrli:monetaryItemType</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><strong> Balance Type:</strong></td>
                    <td>credit</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td><strong> Period Type:</strong></td>
                    <td>instant</td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
</TEXT>
</DOCUMENT>
```

the code is like this but way longer

Comment: Just remove the tags?  That's going to leave a pretty useless blob of text.  How about expanding on the goal and showing us what you have already tried.

Comment: does it make more sense now?

Comment: So you want to **extract** the html tags and not the text in between them?

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I should write it more clear, yes, just throw the whole tags away and leave the text for later.

Comment: This kind of text parsing can get pretty complicated.  I would advise finding a library that can help.  I don't know of any for C++, unfortunately, I'm working in C# these days.  But if you try to parse it brute force, you're asking for a lot of work.

Comment: A couple links:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602332/really-fast-c-html-parser, http://www.mostthingsweb.com/2013/02/parsing-html-with-c/

Comment: @DonBoitnott I see! Thank you so much!! I'm thinking

Answer (score 3):

Since it isn't clear exactly what you are trying to accomplish the solution below breaks an HTML document into individual tags and lines of text. There are probably a few corner cases that are not handled but it does handle attribute strings in case they contain the end tag delimiter. It was written quickly and not much testing has been done so I will leave any necessary fixes up to you. It's not pretty but works and should be enough to get you started.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    std::string html("<div style=\"width: 200px;\"><strong>Balance Sheets (USD $)<br></strong></div>");
    std::vector<std::string>    tags;
    std::vector<std::string>    text;

    for(;;)
    {
        std::string::size_type  startpos;

        startpos = html.find('<');
        if(startpos == std::string::npos)
        {
            // no tags left only text!
            text.push_back(html);
            break;
        }

        // handle the text before the tag    
        if(0 != startpos)
        {
            text.push_back(html.substr(0, startpos));
            html = html.substr(startpos, html.size() - startpos);
            startpos = 0;
        }

        //  skip all the text in the html tag
        std::string::size_type endpos;
        for(endpos = startpos;
            endpos < html.size() && html[endpos] != '>';
            ++endpos)
        {
            // since '>' can appear inside of an attribute string we need
            // to make sure we process it properly.
            if(html[endpos] == '"')
            {
                endpos++;
                while(endpos < html.size() && html[endpos] != '"')
                {
                    endpos++;
                }
            }
        }

        //  Handle text and end of html that has beginning of tag but not the end
        if(endpos == html.size())
        {
            html = html.substr(endpos, html.size() - endpos);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            //  handle the entire tag
            endpos++;
            tags.push_back(html.substr(startpos, endpos - startpos));
            html = html.substr(endpos, html.size() - endpos);
        }
    }

    std::cout << "tags:\n-----------------" << std::endl;

    // auto, iterators or range based for loop would probably be better but
    // this makes it a bit easier to read.    
    for(size_t i = 0; i < tags.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << tags[i] << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "\ntext:\n-----------------" << std::endl;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < text.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << text[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The above code generates the following output (without the space after < since the SO markdown interprets it a an HTML tag like it should)

> ### tags:
>
> < div style="width: 200px;">
>   < strong>
>   < br>
>   < /strong>
>   < /div>
>
> ### text:
>
> Balance Sheets (USD $)

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for help!!! I really appreciate this! just a quick question. Maybe it's because I don't understand HTML well enough.

Comment: as I just edit my original post, when I read those things into an array, I found that they do not nicely break line by line, but rather randomly. break from nowhere sometime. could I ask some suggestions from you? should I just make it a huge string or seeking other ways? thank you!!

Comment: Because it does not check for text blocks that contain _only spaces_ or _new line characters_.

Comment: is there a possible way to solve this? I don't think getline() function will work in this case..

Comment: you can use `std::stringstream`(http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) but that may be a bit heavy. You can also scan the line yourself with a `for` loop and reject ones that contain only white spaces and remove the newline character. Look at the `for` loop that searches for the end of the tag and think about how you might count the white spaces and compare it against the size of the string to see if it contains only whitespaces.

Answer (score 1):

Regular Expressions are not a way to too with HTML. Try using some HTML parsing libraries.
Examples are [Expat](http://expat.sourceforge.net/) or [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/).

These libraries help you to read text representation of entire HTML OR html-tags, their attributes, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying!! Does standard library make it way more difficult? personally, I kind of prefer standard libraries.. just wondering

Comment: I don't think there are any "standard" libraries for this.  You'll likely prefer a 3rd party tool anyhow, for simplicity's sake.

Answer (score 0):

one suggestion is to obtain all tags in html and add them to a hash map
then read a tag(after "<" ) and search it using hash map and made your code act accordingly.